# Построить пирамиду из символов

Tags: java, массивы

Написал метод, который строить пирамиду из символов "^". Саму пирамиду рисует правильно, только вот есть лишний пробел и переход на новую строку, то есть при тестировании пишет

> (Expected: is " ^ \r\n^^^" but: was " ^ \r\n^^^ \r\n")

Как это убрать?

```
public String piramid(int h) {
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < h * 2; j++) {
            if (j > h - 2 - i && j < h + i) {
            builder.append("^");
            } else {
            builder.append(" ");
            }
        }
        builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: Нужно убрать последний пробел и переход на следующую строку. Я же написал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, достаточно добавить дополнительные проверки, а не последние ли это у нас строка/символ? Например, так:

```
public String piramid(int h) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < h * 2; j++) {
            if (j > h - 2 - i && j < h + i) {
                builder.append("^");
            } else if (j < h * 2 - 1) {
                builder.append(" ");
            }
        }
        if (i < h - 1) {
            builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: Да, это сработало, спасибо большое)